# Facebook UI documentation

Tags: facebook, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet to process some Facebook data about my contacts, what will possibly require to load another profile pages and see who my friends are.

I am trying to know which urls should I query to get this information. And also how to interact with FB's UI libraries and/or elements.

Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: [Facebook documentation maybe?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Comment: Or Facebook's SDK in general.

Answer (score -2):

Here is documentation on the FB.ui(): http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui

EDIT:  it's updated by user contributions and lately it hasn't been changed much

Comment: that is **NOT** the documentation for `FB.ui()`.  Here is the real documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: um.. I'm pretty sure it is documentation on FB.ui() and it is real.  I think you're wanting to refer to "official" documentation as opposed to fbdevwiki's documentation.  I linked to it because it has a list of the possible "method"'s available, which the official docs are missing.

Comment: It is documenting the methods - but it is not *the* documentation.  I'm sure it's good stuff - but IMO one should always ( if possible ) reference the original documentation. Taken from their [disclaimer](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FbDevWiki:General_disclaimer) "**This site is not run by Facebook nor endorsed by it...**"